# I have a program that needs to continue when the user enters c

Tags: java, loops

```
import java.util.Scanner;
 public class Example {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
  String inputString;
   char flag = 'y';
   int number = 0;
   int sum = 0;
    while(flag = 'c' && flag = 'C') {
    System.out.print("Enter number to be added");
    number = keyboardInput.nextInt();
    System.out.println("You have entered " + number);
    sum = 0;
     for(int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
     sum = sum + i + 1;
}
     System.out.println("The sum from 1 to " + number + " is " + sum);
     System.out.print("Enter c or C to quit or any other key to continue:");
      keyboardInput.nextLine();
      inputString = keyboardInput.nextLine();
     flag = inputString.charAt(0);
 }
 } 
}
```

Here is the code i have it all figured out except i need to have the program to only continue on when the character c is entered instead of ending when c is entered

Comment: Use `==` to compare `flag` to `'c'` and `'C'`, not `=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `c` like a `flag` not `y` like this:

```
  char flag = 'c';
```

And in your while loop use `==`:

```
   while(flag == 'c' || flag == 'C') {
```

Comment: The condition will always evaluate `false`, because `flag` can never have 'c' AND 'C' at the same time. I suggest using `||`